# Picking photo from web in android no longer includes exif gps location

Tags: android, html, exif-js

I'm developing a website where people can upload images and tag the location.
I'm relying on the exif-info on these to make it easier for users. Until recently this has worked on android, but now this is no longer working. I've debugged and I can read exif, but the location info seems stripped off it. If I move the image to my PC it still works fine (still the exact same website), i can read the GPS coordinates.

So I'm guessing there has been an upgrade to android somehow restricting this from when picking images via the Choose Image dialog/picker.

Is there anyway I can re enable this, either from code or by instructing users to enable it in android?

I'm using a simple html-file input for this (using angular) and exif-js:

```
<label class="btn btn-primary">
        Upload image
        <input #file type="file"
           [accept]="allowedFileTypes" name="file" hidden (change)="onFileChange(file.files)" multiple />
</label>
```

It works in other environments, except for android.

**Update:**

It seems that when I remove the [accept]="allowedFileTypes" I'm able to make it work. I had only accepted jpeg and png, and this seems open a sort of image-picker in android. Accepting all files instead, opens a sort of file-picker which differs a lot in design from the image-picker - and also includes the gps-exif-location.

Since I'm only interested in images I would like to only enable picking images. Any ideas why the exif gps-location is missing when picking images instead of files?

**Update 2:**

Ok, it seems the gps-info is not entirely missing when picking only photos. It is there but all values (in GPSLatitude and GPSLongitude) are 0 (zero), including the denominator which causes the values to become NaN.

Comment: You need MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: And you need a media location permission too.

Comment: How do I acquire that? This is not an app, its a website running in a browser.

Comment: In a browser? In Chrome? Blame Chrome.

Comment: Hello, 2024 here. Just ran into the same issue but the menu picker on android when you don't restrict to .jpg .png etc allows gps data but is a horrible interface. I want the file picker when its restricted to images but need long/latitude value to read the exif from images. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Bumped into the same issue recently in 2023. It seems the android's default 'image' picker blocks the GPS exif for some kind of privacy reason. As a workaround, just don't limit the file types accepted and this will call up the android file explorer.

Through the android file explorer, the GPS exif could be passed to the browser with no issue. All you need to do is to create the file types exception handling frontend and maybe backend as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's an open issue for this in the Chromium bug tracker:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1498162

And another that was closed as a duplicate (but not referenced in the above issue)

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1131001